# Why changing state from false to true throws a Warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a simple client-side login form. When a user logs in the state currentAdmin changes to true (it's false by default). By some reason, setState throws a Warning  *A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type submit to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.*

I tried using refs in Header.js but this didn't help.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from '../Header/Header';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentAdmin: false
    }
  }
  onSignIn = (login, password) => {
    if (login === 'admin' && password === '123') {
      this.setState({
        currentAdmin: true
      })
    }
  }

  onSignout = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentAdmin: false,
    })
  }
render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Header
            onSignin={this.onSignIn.bind(this)}
            onSignout={this.onSignout.bind(this)}
            currentAdmin={this.state.currentAdmin}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App.js;
```

Header.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Header.css';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSignin = this.handleSignin.bind(this);
    this.handleSignout = this.handleSignout.bind(this);
  }

  handleSignin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let login = this.refs.login.value;
    let password = this.refs.password.value;
    this.props.onSignin(login, password);
  }

  handleSignout(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSignout();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.currentAdmin === false) {
       return (
        <div className='header'>
          <a href='google.com' className='logo'>ToDoApp</a>
          <form className='login' onSubmit={this.handleSignin}>
            <input type='text' placeholder='login' ref='login'/>
            <input type='password' placeholder='password' ref='password'/>
            <input type='submit' value='Log in'/>
           </form>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className='header'>
          <a href='google.com' className='logo'>ToDoApp</a>
          <form className='login' onSubmit={this.handleSignout}>
            <input type='submit' value='Log out'/>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Header;
```

This throws a Warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `defaultValue` property on `input` instead of `value`. Check docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values).

As other option - you may want to replace `input type="submit"` with `button type="submit"`

Comment: That's the best option`<button type="submit">Login</button>`

Answer (score 0):

[ALexand Tovmach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10253954/alexandr-tovmach) provided perfect (personally for me) answer. I should have changed `<input type='submit' value='Log in/>`to `<button type='submit'>Log in</button>`